# How to take gradient in Tensorflow for VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a starter in TF, and here is what problem I have encountered:

```
VGG16=tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    classes=1000,
)

x=tf.convert_to_tensor(cats_vs_dogs_array[0][0], dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = VGG16(x)

last_convolutional_layer = VGG16.get_layer('block5_conv3')

dz_dx = g.gradient(last_convolutional_layer.output, VGG16.input) 


print(dz_dx)
```

I am tying to take gradient in this example but it returns none, please help me to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the correct way to do it

```
VGG16=tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224, 224,3),
    classes=1000,
)

x = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(0,1, (1,224,224,3)))
intermediate = Model(VGG16.input, VGG16.get_layer('block5_conv3').output)

with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(x)
    y = intermediate(x)

dz_dx = g.gradient(y, x) 

print(dz_dx.shape)
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you explain why you created an intermediate variable? i want to know the reason, or read about that.

Comment: can you explain what you did?

Comment: I create an intermediate model that extracts the requested intermediate output and then I compute the gradient on input respect to the intermediate layer prediction... don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: yes but where can i see more detailed info? i need to know keras and tf in depth to continue coding by myself.

Comment: here the guide on how to use gradienttape: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape here another reference to train the model with tape https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function you can easily search on the net... don't forget to accept it ;-)

Comment: u don't correctly define the 'intermediate' model on how to compute predictions... you can 't compute the gradients directly on layer input/output